# How to set the font size of navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, font-size

I try to set the fontsize of my navigation title and other items.
How can I do this ?

There are a lot of answers mentoining that we just can set this with the method uinavigationbar.setTitleTextAttributes, but this method doesn't exist (anymore)

Does someone know how to do ?

```
navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, fDialogWidth, navbarHeigth))
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        navigationItem.title = sTitle;
        // Create left and right button for navigation item
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: sBacklabel, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backAction:")
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: saddBookmark, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "addBookmarkAction:")



        // Create two buttons for the navigation item
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem];

        navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenwidth, navbarHeigth);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add these lines to your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Your title" 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Your Font", size: 34)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update for swift 4**

Presumably you want to set the tittle for UINavigationbar with system fontsize 30 and yellow color. The syntax would probably look like the followings:

```
navigationItem.title = "Your Title"    
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30),NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
 let titleAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "your font name", size: 15)!
    ]
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
```

**If you are using system font then**

```
 let titleAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
 ]
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
```